# how to find the higher java version on linux machine with bash or shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, regular-expression, java, version

we need to test and compare java versions

any suggestion for tricky way how to verify if $version > $New_version ?

```
[root@master tmp]#  version=$(java -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}')
[root@master tmp]# echo $version
1.8.0_65
[root@master tmp]# New_version=1.8.0_111
[root@master tmp]# [[ $version > $New_version ]] && echo ok
ok
[root@master tmp]#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GNU sort's version-sort along with the "check if input is sorted" option:

```
printf '%s\n%s\n' "$version" "$New_version" | sort -rVc 2>/dev/null && echo ok
```

The `2>/dev/null` is to drop sort's complaint when the input is not sorted; you just want to know if it's sorted or not, which is reflected in the return code.

Sample run:

```
$ version=1.8.0_65
$ New_version=1.8.0_111
$ printf '%s\n%s\n' "$version" "$New_version" | sort -rVc 2>/dev/null && echo ok
$ version=1.8.0_650
$ printf '%s\n%s\n' "$version" "$New_version" | sort -rVc 2>/dev/null && echo ok
ok
$
```

---

Alternatively, do it the hard way:

```
oldstr=${old//./ }
oldstr=${oldstr//_/ }
newstr=${new//./ }
newstr=${newstr//_/ }
read -a oldarr <<< "$oldstr"
read -a newarr <<< "$newstr"

[ ${oldarr[0]} -ge ${newarr[0]} ] &&
[ ${oldarr[1]} -ge ${newarr[1]} ] &&
[ ${oldarr[2]} -ge ${newarr[2]} ] &&
[ ${oldarr[3]} -gt ${newarr[3]} ] && echo OK
```

This sets up new variables where we replace all of the dots and underscores with spaces, then feed those as here-strings into `read` to split them into arrays, then we compare each element of the parallel arrays.

Comment: can we do printf '%s\n%s\n' "$version" "$New_version" | sort -rVc 2>/dev/null && status=ok || status=fail    ?

Comment: you *could*, since the variable assignment will (should) always succeed, so it won't accidentally trigger the failure-branch's assignment. If it was me, I'd spell it out with an `if printf ... | sort ...; then status=ok; else status=fail; fi`, for clarity